# Python class inheritance to c++

Tags: python, c++, class, inheritance, protected

Before doing a C++ class, I decided to first do it in Python.

There were good sources to do the Python class but I couldn't find useful sources for C++.

Python code:

```py
class Human:
    def __init__(self, first, last, age, sex):
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex
    ...
class Student(Human):
    def __init__(self, first, last, age, sex, school, semester):
        super().__init__(first, last, age, sex)
        self.school = school
        self.semester = semester
    ...
```

C++ code:

```cpp
class Human {
protected:
    string name;
    string lastname;
    int age;
    string sex;
public:
    Human(string name, string lastname, int age, string sex):
    name(name), lastname(lastname), age(age), sex(sex){
    }
    ~Human();
};
class Student: protected Human{
public:
    string school;
    int semester;
    //Student(string school, int semester);
    ~Student();
};
```

how can I do the same thing in my C++ code?

Comment: What is your question? Please read [ask].

Comment: You've obviously got some Python code and some C++ code. In what way is the C++ code not meeting your needs? Again, please read [ask].

Comment: What is it about the python code that you want to emulate in c++ and how does this c++ code not meet those requirements?. It's just straight inheritance. Why does it need to be protected in c++? The python classes expose those members as public (I'll assume thats the case as they dont have a leading underscore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the super constructor and initialize class variables in C++ using an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

As a simplified example:

```
class Human {
   int age;
   string name;
 public:
    Human(string name, int age) : age(age), name(name) {} // initializer list
};

class Student : public Human {
    string school;
 public:
    Student(string name, int age, string school)
        : Human(name, age), school(school) {}  // initializer list
}
```

The `Human(name, age)` part of the student constructor calls the constructor in the base `Human` class.

Your commented out `Student(string school, int semester)` constructor wouldn't be able to properly initialize the `Human` base class as it doesn't contain any information about a `Human` (name, age, sex, etc.).